# Is there any bug in showing "Number Of Pending Messages" in ACTIVE MQ?

Tags: java, web-services, activemq-classic, mule, esb

We are using active mq with Mule ESB JMS for our webservices. It is working fine. But the problem is, even the request is forwarded to my services from queue, processed and giving the response back, but still in the Active MQ web console, Number Of Pending Messages showing the total no.of requests.
Web Console :: 
[image]

Flow diagram,

[image]

Flow in Mule is ::

```
<jms:activemq-connector name="Active_MQ" brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616" validateConnections="true" doc:name="Active MQ"/>
    <flow name="vbrtestmulejmsFlow1" doc:name="vbrtestmulejmsFlow1">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8888" doc:name="HTTP" path="AMServices">
         <set-property propertyName="Content-Type" value="text/xml"/>
        </http:inbound-endpoint>
        <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String" mimeType="text/xml"/>
        <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="servicesQueue" connector-ref="Active_MQ" doc:name="JMS" responseTimeout="1000000" mimeType="text/xml" >
        </jms:outbound-endpoint>

        <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="5050" path="MyServices" method="POST" doc:name="HTTP" contentType="text/xml">
          <set-property propertyName="Content-Type" value="text/xml"/>
        </http:outbound-endpoint>
    </flow>
```

Comment: Not sure I understand, your flow just puts messages on the queue and you never take them off. So isn't it correct that they stay on the queue?

Comment: No, It should forward to MyServices, which are at localhost:5050/MyServices.


But now the request is forward to Myservices and it gives the response back to my SOAPUI.

But still it is showing in pending messages

Comment: It is quite impossible to debug this, as you are not sharing any information about your JMS consumer. Do you experience the same problem if you replace your JMS consumer with a Mule JMS Inbound Endpoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your flow sends the message received by the inbound HTTP endpoint to *both* the JMS outbound endpoint and the HTTP outbound endpoint.

So it's expected that the `servicesQueue` will contain 6 messages and that at the same time `MyServices` gets called 6 times.

Your intention is unclear but if what you wanted instead was to have `servicesQueue` act as an intermediary between the inbound and outbound HTTP endpoints then you need to cut your flow in two:

```
<flow name="AMServiceToQueue">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost"
          port="8888" path="AMServices">
     <set-property propertyName="Content-Type" value="text/xml"/>
    </http:inbound-endpoint>
    <object-to-string-transformer mimeType="text/xml"/>

    <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="servicesQueue" connector-ref="Active_MQ"
         exchange-pattern="request-response" responseTimeout="1000000" />
</flow>

<flow name="QueueToMyServices">
    <jms:inbound-endpoint queue="servicesQueue" connector-ref="Active_MQ"
         exchange-pattern="request-response" />

    <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost"
          port="5050" path="MyServices" method="POST" contentType="text/xml">
      <set-property propertyName="Content-Type" value="text/xml"/>
    </http:outbound-endpoint>
</flow>
```

Comment: This is the single solution to solve all my problems.
Thank you Very much @David Dossot. :)